# How to merge video frame and audio signal in to single stream[Accord]?

Tags: c#, .net, accord.net

I'm capturing video and audio using Accord framework.

```
           //accord video
            videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[0].MonikerString);
            videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);

            //accord audio
            // Create default capture device
            audioSource = new AudioCaptureDevice();
            // Specify capturing options
            audioSource.DesiredFrameSize = 4096;
            audioSource.SampleRate = 22050;

            audioSource.NewFrame += audioSource_NewFrame;



        // capture audio frame
        private void audioSource_NewFrame(object sender, Accord.Audio.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // Read current frame...
            Signal s = eventArgs.Signal;
        }

        private void video_NewFrame(object sender, Accord.Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // get new frame
            Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;

        }
```

Now I can capture video and audio by two different events `audioSource_NewFrame` and `video_NewFrame`.

I want to merge above both video frame and audio into single object to make a video call, May I know the method to do it?

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use VideoFileWriter class instance in both methods.

Here is for Audio:

```
_videoWriter.WriteAudioFrame(e.Signal);
```

And here is for Video:

```
_videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(bitmap, offset);
```